# XML to Database in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, xml, database

I have thousands of XML files

that has many tags and many properties.

I want to put the data in SQL Server table.

The structure of the table is going to be something like this

```
DocumentPath varchar(1000)
Tag          varchar(1000)
ID           varchar(1000)
Attribute    varchar(1000)
Value        varchar(1000)
```

the XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:util="http:///org/" xmi:version="2.0">
    <cas:NULL xmi:id="0"/>
    <tcas:DocumentAnnotation xmi:id="8" sofa="1" begin="0" end="5769" language="x-unspecified"/>
    <structured:DocumentID xmi:id="13" documentID="5"/>
    <structured:DocumentIdPrefix xmi:id="15" documentIdPrefix=""/>
    <structured:DocumentPath xmi:id="35" documentPath="J:\T9.xmi"/>
    <textspan:Segment xmi:id="37" sofa="1" begin="0" end="5769" id="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" preferredText="SIMPLE_SEGMENT"/>
    <textspan:Sentence xmi:id="44" sofa="1" begin="0" end="15" sentenceNumber="0"/>
    <textspan:Sentence xmi:id="50" sofa="1" begin="17" end="32" sentenceNumber="1"/>
    <textspan:Sentence xmi:id="56" sofa="1" begin="37" end="52" sentenceNumber="2"/>
    <syntax:SymbolToken xmi:id="2242" sofa="1" begin="18" end="19" tokenNumber="4"/>
    <syntax:SymbolToken xmi:id="2250" sofa="1" begin="19" end="20" tokenNumber="5"/>
    <syntax:SymbolToken xmi:id="2301" sofa="1" begin="29" end="30" tokenNumber="11"/>
    <syntax:SymbolToken xmi:id="2309" sofa="1" begin="30" end="31" tokenNumber="12"/>
    <syntax:NumToken xmi:id="2258" sofa="1" begin="20" end="24" tokenNumber="6" numType="1"/>
    <syntax:NumToken xmi:id="2275" sofa="1" begin="25" end="26" tokenNumber="8" numType="1"/>
    <syntax:NumToken xmi:id="2292" sofa="1" begin="27" end="29" tokenNumber="10" numType="1"/>
    <syntax:NumToken xmi:id="2381" sofa="1" begin="57" end="61" tokenNumber="20" numType="1"/>
    <textsem:MedicationMention xmi:id="18523" sofa="1" begin="534" end="540" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="18510" typeID="1" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:MedicationMention xmi:id="16831" sofa="1" begin="543" end="547" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="16818" typeID="1" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:MedicationMention xmi:id="16788" sofa="1" begin="558" end="569" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="16753 16773 16763" typeID="1" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:ProcedureMention xmi:id="22518" sofa="1" begin="328" end="343" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="22505" typeID="5" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:ProcedureMention xmi:id="22682" sofa="1" begin="478" end="490" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="22669" typeID="5" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:ProcedureMention xmi:id="22228" sofa="1" begin="495" end="510" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="22215" typeID="5" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:ProcedureMention xmi:id="21938" sofa="1" begin="794" end="809" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="21925" typeID="5" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:ProcedureMention xmi:id="22868" sofa="1" begin="1057" end="1072" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="22855" typeID="5" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:AnatomicalSiteMention xmi:id="24333" sofa="1" begin="786" end="793" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="24320" typeID="6" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:AnatomicalSiteMention xmi:id="25103" sofa="1" begin="842" end="857" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="25090" typeID="6" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:AnatomicalSiteMention xmi:id="23654" sofa="1" begin="842" end="850" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="23641" typeID="6" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:EventMention xmi:id="25137" sofa="1" begin="117" end="124" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="25124" typeID="1003" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:EventMention xmi:id="25201" sofa="1" begin="3448" end="3458" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="25188" typeID="1003" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:EventMention xmi:id="25169" sofa="1" begin="3796" end="3803" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="25156" typeID="1003" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" historyOf="0"/>
    <cas:Sofa xmi:id="1" sofaNum="1" sofaID="_InitialView" mimeType="text"/>
    <structured:SourceData xmi:id="23" noteTypeCode="ClinicalNote" sourceRevisionNbr="0" sourceRevisionDate="2020-03-02 10:48:30"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="18510" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT_US" code="64197008" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0037366" tui="T131" preferredText="Smoke"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="16818" codingScheme="RXNORM" code="746839" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C1999262" tui="T122" preferredText="Pack"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="16753" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT_US" code="410942007" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0013227" tui="T121" preferredText="Pharmaceutical Preparations"/>
    <cas:View sofa="1" members="8 13 15 17 35"/>
</xmi:XMI>
```

The value of `structured:DocumentPath` tag and `documentPath attibute` will be `DocumentPath` in the table

`Tag` is in each line in the XML tag e.g. `textspan:Sentence`

`ID` is the `xmi:id` value

Attribute is each Attribute name
and Value is attributes value

Therefore this line

```
<textspan:Sentence xmi:id="44" sofa="1" begin="0" end="15" sentenceNumber="0"/>
```

will be in the table like this

```
DocumentPath  Tag                 ID    Attribute         Value        
J:\T9.xmi     textspan:Sentence   44    sofa              1
J:\T9.xmi     textspan:Sentence   44    begin             0
J:\T9.xmi     textspan:Sentence   44    end               15
J:\T9.xmi     textspan:Sentence   44    sentenceNumber    0
```

I found this website that shows how to read a simple XML file

[image]

but my case is not the same as number of attributes in each line is dynamic

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The approach is to transform the data to a list and then export it to Sql Server.
You need to read every tag and every attribute (so even if it dynamic it will cache it).
Some packages that can help here:
`lxml.etree` - for read and extract data from the XML.
`pyodbc` - to move the data to Sql Server.

Comment: I have done a similar case, I use one python package `untangle` to parse the XML to python object and then it will easy for you do manipulate the data, then use `sqlalchemy` to insert data to DB, you can definitely try `untangle`. FYI: `pip install untangle` Hope it helps!

Comment: @panda912 can you share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pip intall untangle` to install `untangle`.
One example uses your input:

```
from untangle import parse
your_xml = """.. omit.."""
your_obj = parse(your_xml)
your_obj.xmi_XMI.textspan_Segment._attributes

{'xmi:id': '37',
 'sofa': '1',
 'begin': '0',
 'end': '5769',
 'id': 'SIMPLE_SEGMENT',
 'preferredText': 'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'}
```

As you can see all the data can be accessed like objects.

Comment: Thanks, but getting this error when I run your_obj=parse(your_xml) .. the error is "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-4bb1d5f72a9c>", line 1, in <module>
    your_obj = parse(your_xml)

  File "C:\Users\ASMGX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\untangle.py", line 176, in parse
    if is_string(filename) and (os.path.exists(filename) or is_url(filename)):

  File "C:\Users\ASMGX\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)

ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows"

Comment: Seem your path is too long? Try put it to another folder, you can just paste your XML like str wrapper with `your_xml_str = """xml_content"""`, or you can also open it like file to read from.

Comment: Did not try that on windows, so you got your xml object now?